# Make the "Highly active question" banner link to the "remove new user restrictions" privilege, not the "protect questions" privilege

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, privileges, protected-questions

Currently, the "Highly active question" banner links to the "protect questions" privilege when clicking on the linked text.

Example here:

- [Boundary of Siegel modular variety](https://mathoverflow.net/q/366838/157988)

But the user who is answering is more interested in the answering protected questions privilege, not actually unprotecting it. This can be confusing, especially for users who don't read the article fully as it says 10 reputation in one place but 15,000 in another.

Can the linked text please link to the "remove new user restrictions" privilege?